# Django save() method saving 2 out of 3 fields. No errors are found for the third but won't save

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to modify the field value upon clicking on a tokenized link. It all works as expected except one out of 3 fields does never get updated ('company_name'). The rest do update.
Very simple to showcase what's happening here.

***models.py*** (relevant fields only)

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
        id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
        work_email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True, default="")
        work_email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        company_name = models.CharField(name='Company Name',max_length=100, null=False, blank=True, default="")
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default="")
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, default="")
```

***views.py***

```
class ConfirmWorkEmailView(View):
    def get(self, request, uidb64, token, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
            user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
        except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
            user = None
        if user is not None and work_email_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
            user.work_email_verified = True
            user.first_name = 'Rodrigo'
            user.company_name = 'Cool'
            user.save()
            login(request, user, backend)
            messages.success(request, ('Your company email and name have been verified'))
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.warning(request, ('The verification link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used'))
            return redirect('home')
```

When I reproduce the user's steps and go to the tokenized link, the DB gets successfully updated to True for work_email_verified. Thinking that it'd be something related to the field I also tested changing the name to a ramdon one "Rodrigo" in this case, it turns out first_name also gets updated as expected. Therefore, why is the similar field 'company_name' not getting updated at all?
Please note that I am able to manually update the aforementioned field myself via the below in views.py.

```
class UpdateProfileView(UpdateView): 
   form_class = CustomUserChangeForm
   success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
   template_name = 'update_profile.html'
   def get_object(self, queryset=None):
     return self.request.user
```

Please also note I have also tried using  user=request.user instead and did nothing.
No console errors are shown either.

Thanks so much in advance. Stay frosty.

Comment: Can you try updating the fields after the call to `login`? Thinking it may be this function that is causing the behaviour https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L16

Comment: Thank you @IainShelvington for taking the time to answer this. Unfortunately, it's not worked for me when i try             login(user, backend) instead (it gives me an error after trigger). If I try other combinations the code does not really work either. What else could it be? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

After also testing directly on models.py, I discovered an error in which it said that the 'company name' does not exist in the model when applying the save there.

It turns out that any attribute with a name is not being found on my views.py nor directly on models.py when applying super save there.
I ended up taking out the name option in models.py for company_name leaving it simply as its own attribute name. Django automatically displays Company name on the front-end so this works ok for these purposes and now I'm finally able to save all values via views.py.